# Azera Valve Cover Gaskets

Tags: hyundai, valve-cover

I changed the oil in our '08 Hyundai Azera Limited (3.8L V6 - 93k miles) yesterday. I looked around at the engine while I had the cover off and realized the valve cover gaskets are seeping quite a bit. My plan is to change these out. Having never done this before on this vehicle, I'm wondering what all parts I'm going to need. I know I have to take off the intake plenum in order to get to the rear valve cover (the plenum sits right over the valve cover). Due to this, I'll need to replace the upper plenum gasket. My list of parts I have thus far are:

- FEL-PRO VS50750R - Valve cover gasket set w/Spark plug tube seals; PermaDry molded rubber Gaskets. incl.
- FEL-PRO MS97227 - Plenum Gasket Set; Upper set

Are there any other parts I should be considering for this fix?

Comment: You might as well replace the plugs while you're in there. There's not much else to do... Maybe check for carbon build up on the intake valves...

Comment: @Ben - I did ultimately order those :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most valve cover gaskets suggest/require a dab of RTV silicone be applied on the corners of the head (cover>gasket>silicone>head).  Looking at a picture of said gasket, it may also need a bit to be applied to those 3 rings that run through the inside, but I can't find a source that confirms it one way or another.